# Listener doesn't work when connected to my company network

Tags: oracle, listener

I have a strange problem, the Oracle listener works just fine and has no problems, but when I connect to my company network the listener doesn't work, could any one advise me about that problem?

I am using xe oracle 11.

note: Host set here to "xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.xxx", because I don't know if i'm officially allowed to list my computer name outside my network or not.

### My tnsnames.ora

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.xxx)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

### My listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.xxx)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is "does not work". Is there any error message available?

Comment: If you connect to your company network over a VPN, and the xxx.xxx address resolves into a local LAN address, your VPN might be configured to stop you routing to it - even from the same box. I seem to get that from my company's F5 Firepass system. Or it may resolve differently with a VPN-mandated DNS. Does it work if you change the addresses to 127.0.0.1 in both files; and do other people on your company network need to be able to connect to your listener?

Comment: Hi , thanks for ur replay ,@bpgergo: the error message is ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in con.
@Alex Poole : I tried to use 127.0.0.1 and localhost as well but it didn't work , other can't login to my db as well

Comment: Run `ipconfig` before you connect to your company network, then run it again after you've connected.  Make sure the IP address doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced `RAJESH-PC.xxxxx.xx.com with RAJESH-PC (hostname) or localhost`  in listener.ora and tnsnames.ora `(path oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin)`  and restarted my system. It's working fine after connecting to VPN.

```
listener.ora
===========
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = RAJESH-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

or

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

## tnsnames.ora

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = RAJESH-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

or

XE =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = XE)
)
)

Answer (score 0):

solution 2

Please add below host details in hosts file path( `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` )

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
localhost RAJESH-PC RAJESH-PC.xxxxx.xx.com
127.0.0.1 RAJESH-PC RAJESH-PC.xxxxx.xx.com
```